# Android capture screen using ndk without root permissions

Tags: android, android-ndk, screenshot

I'm trying to find any solution to capture Android screen without root permissions. I used adb for this purpose, but it's too slow ~1-2 fps. Also I've tried to use /dev/graphics/fb0 linux device but this method requires root permissions. For example TeamViewerQS works without root, as I understand they have some pseudo-root permissions.

Maybe there exist some other way which does not requires root?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to find any solution to capture Android screen without root permissions

This should not be possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

> For example TeamViewerQC works without root

Since there does not appear to be anything on the Internet named "TeamViewerQC", I am assuming you are referring to TeamViewerQS. In that case, they are using private APIs from a handful of device manufacturers, in addition to having the user press the key combination to take screenshots.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Sorry it was my mistake, you are right TeamViewerQS. Is there any possibility for me to use private devices API?

Comment: @yaroslav: Contact the device manufacturers and license them. I hope you have a lot of money.